# jQuery if z-index < (less than) 0 then do hover else do something else

Tags: jquery, attributes, z-index, if-statement

I have several layers of photos, stacked on top of each other with different z-index #'s:

```
#layer1 {position: absolute; z-index:-1}
#layer2 {position: absolute; z-index:-2} and so on
```

There are corresponding menu items that when clicked, hide all photo layers and reveal its related layer of photos. I do this by setting the **z-index** of the photo layers behind the background image *(I can't hide, because I need them to load and be ready to display)* and have jquery change the **z-index** on click, then fadeIn.

When hovering over a menu item, I have a preview thumbnail appear, but after I click to reveal a layer, I don't want any of the preview thumbnails to show any longer.

I'm assuming I can use an **if/else** statement

This works on page load `if ($("#layer1").css("z-index") < "0") {` 
however after you click to change the **z-index**, the **if/else** statement still thinks it's the old z-index. Here's a simple js fiddle of what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/YktAZ/52/
Clicking on **MENU 2** should trigger the **else**.

I hope this isn't confusing. Here is the actual website I am working on. Click on COVERS & SPREADS then **hover** or **click** on the new menu items that appear: [URL](http://www.fixxed.com/test/gravite)

Comment: [an `id` starting with a number isn't valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html). I suspect you'll get unpredictable results unless you change that.

Comment: "I can't hide, because I need them to load and be ready to display". Alternatively, you could use `visibility: hidden`. Also, I see nothing related to `z-index` in your jsFiddle, and there is no if/else triggering on click..

Comment: I posted the wrong jsFiddle. I re-edited it and posted the correct one. /sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your jsFiddle, it runs exactly as expected. You've written a statement to execute some code *once* (javascript doesn't sit there looping your code), then you've bound a click handler to change the `z-index` of the image. That's all your click handler does - it *only* changes the z-index of the image. It doesn't rebind the initial hovers or run any other code to change anything.

If you want to alter the hover states you defined at the start of the code, you'll have to run those functions again. You can do this by placing the code in a function, and calling it inside your click handler. Example:

```
function swap_hover() {
    if ($("#image").css("z-index") < "0") {
        $("#menu1").hover(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        }, function() {
            $("#menu1").css("background-color", "white");
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#menu1").hover(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        }, function() {
            $("#menu1").css("background-color", "white");
        });
    }
}

swap_hover();

$("#menu2").click(function() {
    $("#image").css("z-index", "1");

    swap_hover();
});
```

The jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/YktAZ/53/. Once you have a better understanding of javascript, you'll be able to modify this code to do what you actually need it to do.

Comment: Thanks Christian. That's exactly what I was after. Simple stuff, I'm sure, but my knowledge is limited (but growing).

Comment: Haha well you've got to start somewhere, luckily javascript is pretty easy to learn, and you can be building really cool stuff with jQuery quite quickly if you put your mind to it :)